# BigQuery - How to share a wildcard table with users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to share wildcard table with my users.

Hi Guys!

I am trying to share a wildcard table with my users but when I do that, BigQuery just shares e.g. `20230315` but I want to share all tables using `*`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery you can either share individual tables (in your case all current tables individually) or a dataset. If you do share individual tables, this will of course not include any future tables that match the suffix, however sharing a dataset will include view permissions to all the future data in it.

If this is the only set of tables in the dataset, you can share the dataset instead.

You could also create an authorized view with the wildcard table. However, be careful about the amount of data that it would scan if queried.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views

You can also share access on a project level via IAM which would give users access to every dataset and table in the project.

Answer (score -1):

Wildcard tables enable you to query multiple tables using concise SQL statements. Wildcard tables are available only in GoogleSQL. For equivalent functionality in legacy SQL, see Table wildcard functions.

A wildcard table represents a union of all the tables that match the wildcard expression. For example, the following FROM clause uses the wildcard expression gsod* to match all tables in the noaa_gsod dataset that begin with the string gsod.

```
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
```

Each row in the wildcard table contains a special column, _TABLE_SUFFIX, which contains the value matched by the wildcard character.

For information on wildcard table syntax, see Wildcard tables in the GoogleSQL reference.

**Limitations**
Wildcard table queries are subject to the following limitations.

-The wildcard table functionality does not support views. If the wildcard table matches any view in the dataset, the query returns an error. This is true whether or not your query contains a WHERE clause on the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column to filter out the view.

-Currently, cached results are not supported for queries against multiple tables using a wildcard even if the Use Cached Results option is checked. If you run the same wildcard query multiple times, you are billed for each query.

-Wildcard tables support built-in BigQuery storage only.

-You cannot use wildcards when querying an external table or a view.
You cannot use wildcard queries over tables with incompatible partitioning or a mix of partitioned and non-partitioned tables.

-You can use wildcard tables with partitioned tables, and both partition pruning and cluster pruning are supported. However, tables that are clustered but not partitioned don't get any cluster pruning benefit from wildcard usage.
-Queries that contain data manipulation language (DML) statements cannot use a wildcard table as the target of the query. For example, a wildcard table may be used in the FROM clause of an UPDATE query, but a wildcard table cannot be used as the target of the UPDATE operation.

-Filters on the _TABLE_SUFFIX or _PARTITIONTIME pseudo columns that include JavaScript user-defined functions do not limit the number of tables scanned in a wildcard table.

-Wildcard queries are not supported for tables protected by customer-managed encryption keys (CMEK).

-When using wildcard tables, all the tables in the dataset that begin with the table name before * are scanned even if _TABLE_SUFFIX is used in combination with REGEXP_CONTAINS and is provided a regular expression, such as ^[0-9]{2}$. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table_*`
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, '^[0-9]{2}$');
If a single scanned table has a schema mismatch (that is, a column with the same name is of a different type), the query fails with the error Cannot read field of type X as Y Field: column_name. All tables are matched even if you are using the equality operator =. For example, in the following query, the table my_dataset.my_table_03_backup is also scanned. Thus, the query may fail due to schema mismatch. However, if there is no schema mismatch, the results come from the table my_dataset.my_table_03 only, as expected.


SELECT *
FROM my_project.my_dataset.my_table_*
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '03'
```

**Before you begin**
-Ensure that you are using GoogleSQL. For more information, see Switching SQL dialects.
-If you are using legacy SQL, see Table wildcard functions.
-Many of the examples on this page use a public dataset from the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA). For more information about the data, see NOAA Global Surface Summary of the Day Weather Data.

**When to use wildcard tables**
Wildcard tables are useful when a dataset contains multiple, similarly named tables that have compatible schemas. Typically, such datasets contain tables that each represent data from a single day, month, or year. For example, a public dataset hosted by BigQuery, the NOAA Global Surface Summary of the Day Weather Data, contains a table for each year from 1929 through the present.

A query that scans all the table IDs from 1929 through 1940 would be very long if you have to name all 12 tables in the FROM clause (most of the tables are omitted in this sample):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  max,
  ROUND((max-32)*5/9,1) celsius,
  mo,
  da,
  year
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1929` UNION ALL
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1930` UNION ALL
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1931` UNION ALL

  # ... Tables omitted for brevity

  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod1940` )
WHERE
  max != 9999.9 # code for missing data
ORDER BY
  max DESC
```

The same query using a wildcard table is much more concise:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  max,
  ROUND((max-32)*5/9,1) celsius,
  mo,
  da,
  year
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod19*`
WHERE
  max != 9999.9 # code for missing data
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '29'
  AND '40'
ORDER BY
  max DESC
```

Wildcard tables support built-in BigQuery storage only. You cannot use wildcards when querying an external table or a view.